# Cocos2dx RegisterTouchDispatcher

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have started using cocos2d-x in iphone. I have created a class which inherits from cclayer. Now when I try to register it with touch dispatcher it crashes.

In .h file:

class BasePage : public cocos2d::CCLayer

And .m file:

```
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this, INT_MIN + 1, true);
```

And it crashes in ccobject.m file:

```
void CCObject::retain(void)
{
    CCAssert(m_uReference > 0, "reference count should greater than 0");[here is crash]

    ++m_uReference;
}
```

Can you please give me some solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
bool SampleLayer::init()
{
   if (!CCLayer::create())
          return false;


    setTouchEnabled(true);

    return true;
}

void SampleLayer::onEnter()
{

CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this, 0, true);
    CCNode::onEnter();

}

void SampleLayer::onExit()
{

    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->removeDelegate(this);
    CCNode::onExit();

}

bool SampleLayer::ccTouchBegan(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event)
{
    return true;
}

void SampleLayer::ccTouchMoved(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event)
{}

void SampleLayer::ccTouchEnded(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event)
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write only this line in .m(or .cpp) file

```
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addStandardDelegate(this, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact you don't need to implement your own RegisterTouchDispatcher.

just call the method below in constructor or onEnter

```
setTouchEnabled(true);
setTouchMode(kCCTouchesOneByOne);
```

the base class will do all the mess for you .

besides , you should set touch mode to **kCCTouchesAllAtOnce** if you wanna enable muti-touch

ps: if you override onEnter in your own class ,remenber to call **BaseClass::onEnter()** in your own onEnter function , 
like

```
MyLayer::onEnter()
{
    CCLayer::onEnter();
    // do my own stuff
}
```